# initialize a string within a linq query

Tags: c#, string, initialization, sitecore

In Sitecore, I have a container which contains a lot of child items.

These child items all contains a `string`, which I want to have stored in a 
`public IEnumerable<string> Descriptions;` collection.

```cs
public SelectionViewModel(Item datasource)
{
    if (datasource.HasChildren)
    {
        Descriptions = datasource.Children
            .InnerChildren
            .Where(item => 
                TemplateManager.GetTemplate(item).InheritsFrom(Template.Info.Id))
            .SelectMany(item => new string(item[Template.Info.Field.Information]))
    }
}
```

The last line don't seem to be possible as I am not able to initialize a string with a string. How do I populate my `IEnumerable`?

Comment: Have you tried this without trying to create a new string object? Like: `.SelectMany(item => item[Template.Info.Field.Information]);`?

Comment: did not work eiter..

Comment: What do you mean by `did not work`? Was there an error message? Is the `Descriptions` collection just empty or missing some items?

Comment: The collection is empty, and I had to change it to char enumerable.

Comment: How many child items are we talking about? Can you give an estimate of "lot of child items". Also are you sure they are direct children of the datasource?

Comment: ^ this should work:
```item => item[Template.Info.Field.Information].ToString()```

Answer (score 0):

From comments I suppose the code should be:

```
public SelectionViewModel(Item datasource)
{
    if (datasource.HasChildren)
    {
        Descriptions = datasource.Children
            .InnerChildren
            .Where(item => 
                TemplateManager.GetTemplate(item).InheritsFrom(Template.Info.Id))
            .Select(item => item[Template.Info.Field.Information]).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably best to realize the projection to overcome lifetime issues of the Sitecore context. Finish it up with a `.ToArray()`